# Read a text file using LinQ and then insert it into SQL Table using LinQ To SQL

Tags: sql, linq, linq-to-sql, streamreader

as you see this is a simple code to read a file and print the lines separated by comma into a listbox. I'm just starting to learn LinQ and I need some examples using this easy one. I need to convert this code to LinQ and then insert the results into a SQL Table using LinQ to objects. I believe I can do the insertion but I need to save this with Linq to an array or list so I can point it to the right direction. Please any help will be highly appreciated.

```
  StreamReader file = new StreamReader(@"C:\Files\Archivo.txt");
        string line;

        while((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {

        string[] fields = line.Split(',');


        foreach (string word in fields)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(word);
        }
        }
```

Comment: good soure of linq examples - http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without proper testing, I believe this will help:

```
File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Files\Archivo.txt").SelectMany(s => s.Split(',')).ToList();
```

This will read all lines from your file, split on the ',', flatten the array and return a `List<string>`. You can then even add an extra `Select` at the end to enumerate the collection and create you objects from this. There are plenty of examples of how to do that on stackoverflow and elsewhere on the internet.

Comment: Thank you Ric, it was helpful. Now Im trying to figure out how to insert the lines read on the text file and insert them into the Linq sql table. Thank you!

Comment: after the select many, use something like this Select(x => new EntityObject() {Property1 = x.ToString()).ToList() where EntityObject is the new object to create! shouldn't be too difficult.